PHP 8.3 on IIS 10 can't get document root set properly
I'm stuck on migrating old website to new server and the problem is on "include" or "require".
Website is on h:\www and doc_root and include_path in php.ini are set to h:\www.
If I include a file in subdirectory of h:\www, php say "Failed Opening".
Example:
include("/Include/ciao.txt"); doesn't work
include("Include/ciao.txt"); Work
I've a lot of inclusion in my documents, can't simply rename them all.
I made several echo testing all this and I see a strange behavior....
ini_get('include_path') -> H:\WWW
getcwd() -> H:\WWW
realpath("/") -> H:\
I think the problem is here, on the last echo but  I can't figure how make this work.
If I echo realpath("/") on my old server it always report document root.
Any help would be appreciated, thank

/Include/ciao.txt refers to the filesystem root, not the document root.

"realpath("/") on my old server it always report document root" Are you sure? On which OS was it?

/Include/ciao.txt" refer to a file in "c:\www\Include\ciao.txt", not system folder.
realpath("/") on my old servers it always report document root on windows and ubuntu too. I can't get where I've configured this earlier if i've configured before...

According to your description, it seems to be the difference between relative path and absolute path？If possible, you can try to use the URL Rewrite module of IIS to process the include_path file so that it points to the correct directory. Something like <match url="^Include/(.*)$" /> <action type="Rewrite" url="H:/WWW/Include/{R:1}" />.

Perhaps your old server literally had "H:\" as document root (or whatever driver letter is was) and in the new one you've created a WWW directory. It's very important to be aware of the difference between file systems paths (the ones you use to manipulate files in your own hard disk) and network locations (which you use to request resources from a network service, and more often than not do not map to file system locations).
